# Vagrant + Laravel Homestead + Excluding nested directories from sync

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, rsync, homestead

I am trying to exclude some directories from syncing. Below is my `Folder` values for the project directory in `homestead.yaml`

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Dropbox/Sisir Workspace/projects/www
      to: /var/www
      options:
            :type: "rsync"
            :rsync__exclude: [".git/", "vendor/", "node_modules/"]
```

But this doesn't seem to work. When I `vagrant up` it runs without any error. But when i create even a file into the vm the file is not created in the mapped directory and vice versa.

**OS**: Ubuntu 16.04

**VM**: Virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'rsync' as a type for syncing the folder.

Add the next line above options

```
type: "rsync"
```